# Locate stolen 2015 MacBook Pro with no location on Find My

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, geolocation, find-my-mac

A friend said he could replace the screen on our 2015 MacBook Pro with Retina display. He sold the laptop to his cousin and we don’t know who or where he is, but he told us to pay him the money he paid to get it back.

I keep checking the Find My app but every time I check it says

> MacBook Pro *OFFLINE*
> ☑ Notify Me When Found

‘Notify Me When Found’ is checked. We’ve locked the MacBook Pro already but it says

> **Sound & Lock Pending**
> Pending actions will take effect when this Mac connects to the Internet

I clicked on lock again and it says

> Lock requested on February 26 at 6:34 PM

but don’t know why it still says the sound and lock is pending.

Other than the Find My app is there any other away that I can locate/track/find our 2015 MacBook Pro?

We have also been told that the person who has our MacBook Pro laptop still hasn't been able to get into the laptop, so not sure how to find the location, if the person has erased our Apple ID from it, or if it still has all our accounts and info still on it or not.

Comment: Seems like a clear case for the police.

Answer (score 1):

The lock is pending since Apple has not delivered the payload to the device. It needs to connect to the internet and talk with Apple servers for that.

You likely need non-technical means to locate this hardware as you’ve done all you can with Apple’s location software.